# What does VNC server do when a client connects? (Ultr@ VNC)

Tags: performance, vnc, ultravnc

I have a low spec Windows XP computer which is generally really slow. However, when I connect via VNC the computer speeds up. What does VNC do when a client connects? Something VNC server does is increasing the performance of the computer and I would like it turned on all the time.

I am using Ultr@ VNC, the computer fan speed even gets quieter when someone connects via VNC!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only settings the VLC server will change on an incoming are the backgrounds and visual effects. Try turning off all the effects in the display properties control panel.